# Does Vim have a certain syntax to combine commands on command mode?

Tags: vim, syntax, command, vi

I noticed some syntaxes when i use vim

for example

```
[<motion>]<operator><motion>

e.g.

<gg><d><G> // delete from the top of file to the bottom of file
    <d><G> // delete from the current line to the bottom of file
```

and for

```
<operator><operator>

e.g.

<y><y> // inline copy
<d><d> // inline delete
<>><>> // inline right-indent
```

OK, something like these.

For the syntax or the way to combine the command i know just a few patterns.

And for me i think there are so many ways to combine commands on vim it looks too messy for me

I think Vim should have a basis of command.

I would like to know that

Does vim have a certain syntax to combine the commands?

Can you give me a further information about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of actions as sentences and commands as words in that sentence: verbs, objects, prepositional phrases, modifiers grouped in that sentence according to a grammar that (like most grammars) has its corner cases but makes a lot of sense overall. Hell, Vim even has transitive and intransitive verbs!

The basic rules are really quite simple:

```
{count}operator{motion}
{count}operator{text-object}
```

If you have a clear idea of the action you want to perform, using Vim's language is almost friction-less.

"Cut this block of lines and paste it below the function signature." could become:

```
dip                           " cut this paragraph
?func<CR>                     " move the cursor to the first func above
p                             " paste
```

instead of the incredibly convoluted:

```
<Home>                        " move the cursor to the start of the line
<Shift><Down><Down><Down>     " select the block I want to move
<C-x>                         " to cut the selection
<Up><Up><Up><Up><Up><Up><Up>  " move up to the target
<End>                         " move the cursor at the end of the line
<CR>                          " open a new line 
<C-v>                         " (finally) paste those lines
```

(edit)

The example above stands as a good illustration of the beauty of Vim's editing model: there's very little to none "delta" between what you think and what you actually do. In more traditional editors, that "delta" can be *huge* because of all the completely unrelated steps necessary to perform a given task. Because using Vim is like speaking a language with your fingers, you only have to *think* in that language to be efficient. What you gain from that is more than speed.

(endedit)

"Paste 6 times." becomes the awesome:

```
6p                            " paste 6 times
```

instead of:

```
<C-v><C-v><C-v><C-v><C-v><C-v>
```

Other interesting rules:

- lowercase motions (`bwe`) work on keyword characters-delimited `words`,
- uppercase motions (`BWE`) work on whitespace-delimited `WORDS`,
- some uppercase operators (`FTP`) work just like their lowercase counterparts but in the opposite direction,
- some uppercase operators (`IA`) work like their lowercase counterparts but on the extremities of the line,
- some other uppercase operators (`YCDVS`), like doubled lowercase operators (`yyddcc`) are shortcuts for very common `operator{motion}` sentences…

Glts has written [an awesome article](http://glts.github.io/2013/04/28/vim-normal-mode-grammar.html) on the subject.